# Open courseware for Linear Algebra

Tags: soft-question

I want to self study LA and I have 2 options for open courseware: MIT and khanacademy. Which one do you guys think is more thorough and would you recommend for a beginner? Of course, I also have books on the subject but I want to use one of these 2 for my study too, I don't know which one though, but seem good, I am leaning towards khanacademy, but not sure..

Comment: Like the difference between a fast food restaurant and real food, it is a matter of taste.

Comment: @André The opposite of fast food actually is [slow food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_food)!

Comment: That is extremely vague.. I assume you mean that they're both equally adequate?

Comment: No. The MIT course is serious. The Khan stuff I have seen (in Calculus, not Linear Algebra) is "how-to", although pretty well done how-to.

Comment: Yes, I thought beforehand that the MIT one would be more serious and thorough, however, the sound quality (and sometimes video quality) is terrible, it does have subtitles, but extremely lagging subtitles.. so I think I'll start off with khanacademy's course.

Comment: [Pay it forward](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer). If an answer is useful to you, consider upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIT OCW (if it's Strang) is nice, but is more geared to engineers, focusing on matrix mechanics.

Although this is useful, if you are interested in a more rigorous, math treatment that will also be subsequently quite useful in further studies of algebra, I would recommend these two courses.

They both use "Linear Algebra Done Right" which (despite it's awful title) is widely used in math programs. These two websites generously offer a great deal of very helpful material.

http://math.mit.edu/~trasched/18.700.f11/index.html

http://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math110-spring12/

Answer (score 0):

I am awaiting January entry in a advanced linear math. I have been using both, Khan's academy I think would be the way to go the videos are very instructive. The MIT course might be more weighty.